# pip install pygame not working in windows 8.1 however I already gave path by ( C:\Python34\ ). What should I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pygame, pip

I'm trying to install `pygame` in python 3.4.3 but it gave error as shown in the picture. However, I already gave the path variable `(C:\Python34)`, but it isn't working.

How can I solve the problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "error as shown in picture" - Where is the picture?

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer  Hidden.  There is another edit going through so I can't get the link.  The're just trying pip install through the interpreter so obviously it won't work

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the info! Well, I think the answers below answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should do pip install pygame in the command prompt. If you do not have pip, install it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong thing.  `pip` is an application like Python.  It is not part of the Python library nor is it an integrated function, to use it you must open Command Prompt (assuming your on Windows) not the Python interpreter, to do this type in search (or Cortana) and enter "cmd", when it appears click on it.

Now that you have opened command prompt retry your commands in that window and it should work.